# Finding an optimal orientation and the oriented diameter of a given graph

Tags: mathematical-optimization, graphs-and-networks, distance

**I am wanting to specify a graph (a collection of vertices and edges) and find the optimal orientation of that graph.**

*An orientation of an undirected graph is an assignment of a direction to its every edge. An optimal orientation is an orientation that
maximizes reachability (A vertex v is reachable from a vertex u if there is a path from u to v).*

**Furthermore, I want to find the numerical value of the oriented diameter of that graph.**

*The distance between two vertices u and v in a graph (or digraph) G is the length of a shortest path from u to v in G. The maximum of all the distances between two vertices in a graph (or digraph) G is called the diameter of G. The oriented diameter of G is the smallest diameter among all strong orientations of G.*

I have written a code, but there are major problems with it. Firstly, it keeps telling me that my graph is optimally oriented, even when I know it isn't. Secondly, it does not output the actual orientation nor the actual oriented diameter, both of which are crucial.
I get an error message: "GraphPeriphery::graph: A graph object is expected at position 1 in GraphPeriphery[Graph[True,VertexLabels->Name,DirectedEdges->True]]."

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
    (*Define the graph*)vertices = Range[7];
edges = {1 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
   2 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 
   4 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 
   5 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 
   7 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 7 \[DirectedEdge] 2};

graph = Graph[vertices, edges, VertexLabels -> "Name"];

(*Find the optimal orientation*)
optimalOrientation = 
  Graph[vertices, DirectedEdge @@@ edges, VertexLabels -> "Name"] // 
   WeaklyConnectedGraphQ;

If[optimalOrientation, 
 Print["The graph is already optimally oriented."], 
 Print["The graph is not optimally oriented. Finding optimal \
orientation..."];
 optimalOrientation = 
  Graph[vertices, DirectedEdge @@@ edges, VertexLabels -> "Name"] // 
   GraphOrientation[#, "Optimal"] &;
 Print["Optimal orientation: ", optimalOrientation]]

(*Compute the oriented diameter*)
orientedDiameter = 
  GraphPeriphery[
   Graph[optimalOrientation, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
    DirectedEdges -> True]];

Print["Oriented diameter: ", Max[orientedDiameter]]
```